# Embedded Jetty Response

Tags: java, response, embedded-jetty

I am using the embedded version of jetty. I have noticed the following:

in the handler method, if I want to directly respond with an HTTP OK response, then sleep for x seconds, the handler is doing the opposite. Is this normal?

the handle function is the following:

```
public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

response.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            baseRequest.setHandled(true);
            response.getWriter().println("OK");

Thread.sleep(10000);

}
```

The bastard is sleeping 10 seconds then returning the response, why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call

```
response.flushBuffer();
```

before you sleep the Thread.

From the JavaDoc of this method:

> Forces any content in the buffer to be written to the client. A call
>   to this method automatically commits the response, meaning the status
>   code and headers will be written.

Comment: I tried it and I got the OK response back, however the Connection is not being closed until the Thread.sleep() function is done. I am telnetting to be honest.

Comment: I don't know how to close the connection before the exit of the handle method. But why do you need to wait after closing the connection? It seems strange to me.

Comment: Oh well I just added the sleep time as an example of some operation taking place after the response is sent. Oh well, thanks anyhow, this should suffice for the time being my friend!